# PSQL, sum or count values grouped by a new set characteristic

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a data table that looks like

```
name   breed
Mina   Persian
Lara   Asian
Mauri  Labrador
George Huskey 
Patri  Golden Retriever
```

and I would like to count by a new variable related to the breed, in this case I would like to count Persian, Asian as Cats and Labrador, Huskey, Golden Retriever as Dogs. So my output is:

```
breed  count 
Cats   2
Dogs   3
```

I have something like:

```
select 
  a.name,
  a.stage,
  count(*)
from 
  animals a 
group by
  a.breed
```

Comment: Also if you have a more correct title for the post, let me know, thanks in advance

Comment: You will need either another column or table that associates a  breed with a breed type e.g. cat or dog.

Comment: In this particular case is not necessary to differentiate that, the original code has other type of data that is compatible with leaving the same column name. Maybe my example is not as homologous

Comment: Then show the original code. As it stands the query  you show is not going to return the output you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an additional column `species` with a case statement, and then perform a group by and count on top of that.

If your mysql version supports CTEs (common table expressions):

```
with animal_species as (
    select *, 
           case when breed in ('Persian', 'Asian') then 'Cats'
                when breed in ('Labrador', 'Huskey', 'Golden Retriever') then 'Dogs'
                else 'Unknown'
           end as species
    from animals 
)
select species, count(*) 
from animal_species 
group by species
```

If your mysql version does not support CTEs:

```
select species, count(*)
from (
    select *, 
               case when breed in ('Persian', 'Asian') then 'Cats'
                    when breed in ('Labrador', 'Huskey', 'Golden Retriever') then 'Dogs'
                    else 'Unknown'
               end as species
    from animals 
) a
group by species
```